# Rendering month field in mother language Symfony2 TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, locale

I'm trying to translate the months of the DateType to Bulgarian, the methods that I tried so far are:

In the Controller:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "bg_BG");
```

just before:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($reservation)
```

but the field is rendered again in English.

I already have this defined in config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: bg
```

and

```
framework:
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

nothing helps so far

Answer (score 0):

Do you only require that one form to be rendered in Bulgarian or the whole project?

You will need to create an event listener first to achieve this

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    // some logic to determine the $locale
    $request->setLocale($locale);
}
```

It sounds like the Locale isn't being set before you create the form. As explained by Symfony.

> Setting the locale using $request->setLocale() in the controller is
>   too late to affect the translator. Either set the locale via a
>   listener (like above), the URL (see next) or call setLocale() directly
>   on the translator service.

If you're wanting to set the locale for the whole application in Bulgarian, I would recommend setting a default locale in your config.

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    default_locale: bg
```

So it can be called anywhere.

There's more information here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#handling-the-user-s-locale

Comment: I already set the default locale in the config, but no result.

Comment: Did you clear your cache after your changes? Sometimes you need to do that. I'm not certain of the Symfony2 command, but in Symfony3 it's: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` and remove "--env=prod" for your dev environment as well.